# mongoose find not returning results when mongodb it does

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Based on [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7573/difference-between-mongodbs-find-and-findone-calls) and [this issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1692) `find` is faster than `findOne` if the query is not executed, so I'm trying to do so in node.js.

In mongodb (cli) I'm executing the following command:

```
> db.carts.find({_id: ObjectId("57bd3df5c878685d3ec581d6")}).limit(1).count()
1
```

Then in node.js, using mongoose I'm using this code which always returns 0:

```
const cartId = '57bd3df5c878685d3ec581d6';
const query = Cart.find({ _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(cartId) }).limit(1);
console.log(query.count()); // 0
```

Also noted that if query is executed then it returns the cart:

```
query.exec().then(console.log); // [ { _id: 57bd3df5c878685d3ec581d6, __v: 0, ...
```

Here it is the Cart model:

```
const cartSchema = new Schema({
    cartItems: [],
    cartItemsCount: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    cartTotal: {
        EUR: {
            value: { type: Number, default: 0 },
            currencyPrec: { type: Number, default: 2 },
            count: { type: Number, default: 0 },
        },
    },
    cartTotalInEur: {
        itemsCost: { type: Number, default: 0 },
        shippingCost: { type: Number, default: 0 },
        discounts: {
            quantity: { type: Number, default: 0 },
            percent: { type: Number, default: 0 },
            couponCode: String,
        },
        tax: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    },
    shippingInfo: {
        email: String,
        receiver: String,
        street: String,
        postcode: String,
        city: String,
        country: {
            name: String,
            'alpha-2': String,
            'alpha-3': String,
            'sub-region-code': String,
            'region-code': String,
            'sub-region': String,
            region: String,
        },
        isUrgent: Boolean,
        isSaveData: Boolean,
    },
    created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    updated: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});
const Cart = mongoose.model('cart', cartSchema);
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you show your model declaration for Cart/carts?  Wondering if there could be an issue there.

Comment: Can you try `Cart.find({ _id: cartId }).limit(1).count();` ?

Comment: @L.Meyer I've already tried, with same result (originally it was my first trial :)

Comment: I don't see your callback. [Here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-count) is an example.
`query.count((err, c) => console.log(c))`

Comment: @L.Meyer thanks, the problem is that _Passing a callback executes the query._ and I would like to avoid it, just want the cursor to see whether if there exists a cart or not, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen lowercase for the model name.  Shouldn't it be:

```
const Cart = mongoose.model('Cart', cartSchema);
```